# Paypal user to user transaction using php webservice

Tags: php, paypal

My Requirement: We have an iphone app which will accept paypal login id and password of user and our web service should authenticate those details and if the user is a valid one, on next web service call will accept the details of second user and amount to transfer and the web service should make the payment automatically (without redirecting to paypal site).

Is there any facility available in paypal for this functionality. I have gone through adaptive payments of paypal but didn't find anything related to authentication. We have written the web service in php. Any sample code/ links would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this is what you're after](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/).  Specifically [Login with PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/log-in-with-paypal/) and [Seamless Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/seamless-checkout/).

You might also want to look at [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/), specifically [Preapproval](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/) and [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I want to transfer one user account to another user account. For second user, I will be having only the email id. In seamless checkout, I can not see this feature. Please help

Comment: I updated the answer with some links to what I think would help.  Your users would setup Preapproval for your app to make payments on their behalf.  This is done just once.  Then your app can make payments on their behalf without any further approval, so you can trigger those payments however you want.